# How to resolve one to many relation between dimension tables

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have the following scenario. 
I have a transaction table which contains the facts at customer level. 
Multiple customers are grouped into customer group. Each customer group is tied to single product.

So we have 1 to many relationships between product and customer Group.
1 to Many relationship between customer Group and customer.
Txn facts are at customer level.

Therefore how do I dimensionally model customer and product info without duplicating data?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your facts truly at the customer level, or do they/should they really relate to a customer group? For example an account balance fact could be an account balance for an account, which is one product, and if a joint account could be for a customer group. If so I'd focus on your facts rather than the customer to product relationship (itself a fact). For either situation, customer groups can be represented by 'bridge' tables as one solution (so research those), but there are other solutions. Note, 'without duplicating data' should not be the major concern in a dimensional model.

Comment: Thanks Rich for the response.I have been asked to produce a model to report  txn facts at product level. This is why it gets trickier. I presume bridge table can be built with product customer key to link between fact (as fact already contains customer id) and product table. Is this right way of approaching? My understanding of dimensional model is that dimensions should be lower grain and joined to facts with 0/1 to many relationships. That is the reason I have mentioned without duplicating data. Why duplication is not a concern?

Comment: Is there a reason the product isn't already in the transaction fact? A bridge table in this case would just be a representation of your customer group. The customer group key (from the bridge) can then participate in a fact. And the fact could, if you wish, be a fact representing the relationship between customer groups and products. The bridge table isn't a bridge between products and customers- that's a fact in its own right. A dimension isn't a 'lower grain', its just one row per item in a real dimension. You're right about the 1: Many relationships...

Comment: ..but the duplication of the relationship between customer groups and products should not be a concern- if you need to duplicate data, that's fine as long as the model makes sense.  I think I could help you more on this, but you will need to update your question to include examples of the situations you are describing, like what your transaction facts describe (or are intending to describe), and what it means for a customer group to be related to a product. Happy to help more once more info available.

Comment: Thanks Rich. Let me give you some more insights. I have txn table with few measures at customer level. Customers are grouped in Customer Groups. A product is sold to many customer groups (1 to many) . Each Customer Group is Managed by a consultant who is at region level. I need to produce a report with txn measures by region by product. How do I model it effectively?

Comment: Yes, the product can be at fact table. Now the only question is how do I link customer and customer group with txn facts?

Comment: If your customer group is linked to customer, and if your customer is in the txn fact, doesn’t that do it? Please give examples of your txn facts. (Also, what did you think of bridge tables when you researched them?)